# Subscribe to ZeroMq using akka scala

Tags: scala, akka, zeromq, akka-stream, akka-zeromq

I am trying to subscribe to zeromq message and then convert the messages to akka streams. Can anyone please point me to the right approach to do so?

Comment: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3/scala/zeromq.html (first search in google: akka+zeromq). Even better, couple search results down: https://github.com/2gis/reactive-zmq.

Comment: I tried using reactive-zmq, I am not receiving any zmq messages.

Comment: Akka 2.3 has been EOL:ed a couple of years already and is not something to use for a new project.